# How to make nativescript-i18n to work with Nativescript 2.3/Angular 2?

Tags: internationalization, nativescript

Thw documentation at the nativescript-i18n site [shows](https://github.com/rborn/nativescript-i18n) how to set it up with NS 2.2 and earlier Angular 2 rc releases:

```
    import {I18N_PROVIDERS} from 'nativescript-i18n/angular';

    import {nativeScriptBootstrap} from "nativescript-angular/application";
    // (The following import is just a component designed as the main application component.)
    import {Explorer} from "./components/explorer/explorer";

    nativeScriptBootstrap(Explorer, [ I18N_PROVIDERS ]);
```

However, this setup does not work with the final release of Angular 2 with Nativescript 2.3.  How to adapt to the final Angular 2 release?

Comment: This repository is no longer maintained. https://github.com/rborn/nativescript-i18n